# C++ std::vector problems

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm trying to port a few classes from java to c++.

So let's say that we have this 2 classes:

```
class ForwardNetwork {
protected:
    ForwardLayer* inputLayer;
    ForwardLayer* outputLayer;
    vector<ForwardLayer* > layers;
public:
    void ForwardNetwork::getLayers(std::vector< ForwardLayer* >& result ) {
        for(int i= 0 ;i< layers.size(); i++){
            ForwardLayer* lay = dynamic_cast<ForwardLayer*>(this->layers.at(i));
            if(lay != NULL)
                result.push_back(lay);
            else cout << "Layer at#" << i << " is null" << endl;
        }

    }
    void ForwardNetwork::addLayer ( ForwardLayer* layer ) {
        if(layer != NULL)
            cout << "Before push layer is not null" << endl;
        //setup the forward and back pointer
        if ( this->outputLayer != NULL ) {
            layer->setPrevious ( this->outputLayer );
            this->outputLayer->setNext ( layer );
        }
        //update the input layer and outputLayer variables
        if ( this->layers.size() == 0 )
            this->inputLayer = this->outputLayer = layer;
        else this->outputLayer  = layer;

        //push layer in vector
        this->layers.push_back ( layer );

        for(int i = 0; i< layers.size();i++)
            if(layers[i] != NULL)
                cout << "Check::Layer[" << i << "] is not null!" << endl;
    }

void ForwardNetwork::reset() {
   std::cout<< "Network size#" << this->layers.size() << std::endl;
   int index = -1;
   for ( int i = 0; i< this->layers.size(); i++ ){
       cout << "Layer[" << i << "] address#" << layers[i] << endl;
       if(layers[i] != NULL){
         layers[i]->reset();
       }
       else cout << "Layer NULL";
  }
}
};
```

Second class:

```
class Backpropagation : public Train {
public:
    Backpropagation::Backpropagation ( ForwardNetwork* network ){
        this->network = network;
        vector<ForwardLayer*> vec;
        network->getLayers(vec);
    }
};
```

Main function:

```
ForwardNetwork* network = new ForwardNetwork();
ForwardLayer* layer2= new ForwardLayer(2);
network->addLayer(layer2);
ForwardLayer* layer3 = new ForwardLayer(3);
network->addLayer(layer3);
ForwardLayer* layer1 = new ForwardLayer(1);
network->addLayer(layer1);
network->reset();
Train* train = new Backpropagation(network);
```

Now if i add from main() some layers into network via addLayer(..) method it's all good.My vector is just as it should.But after i call Backpropagation() constructor with a network object ,when i enter getLayers(), some of my objects from vector have their address set to NULL(they are randomly chosen:for example if i run my app once with 3 layer's into vector ,the first object from vector is null.If i run it second time first 2 objects are null,third time just first object null and so on).
Now i can't explain why this is happening.I must say that all the objects that should be in vector they also live inside the network and they are not NULL;

This happens everywhere after i done with addLayer() so not just in the getLayers().
I cant get a good grasp to this problem.I thought first that i might modify my vector.But i can't find such thing.
Also why if the reference from vector is NULL  ,the reference that lives inside ForwardNetwork as a linked list (inputLayer and outputLayer) is not NULL?

PS: as compiler i use g++ part of gcc 4.6.1 under ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Whenever you write `vector<SomeType*>` it is probably wrong.  You don't need to store pointers in a vector and it is actually a bad thing.  You are circumventing the container's ability to manage memory for you.

Comment: It seems to me that there are some valid use cases for a vector of pointers, what if the vector is holiding the results of some algorithm performed on another vector<T> for example would you always want to copy them all?  I would say that in that instance though a vector<shared_ptr<T>> is probably the way to go these days.

Comment: Wouldn't a vector of shared_ptr introduce memory overhead and also bookkeeping overhead whenever the vector has to reallocate its internal storage?

Comment: I'm on my way to see what's going with these smart pointers.

Comment: Can you post your `main()` code? That way we can see how you're using these classes.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried the vector<shared_ptr<T>> method and it seems to introduce a 25% runtime overhead in my test case.

Comment: I just inserted the main code.See my first post.I also want to ask if shared_ptr it's a part of STL.The reason is that i included <memory> but can't get it.If i search on the net i only foud references to boost library.Although i found a reference on MSDN where it seem's Microsoft included shared_ptr in their vc++ library.

Comment: @hc_: Try `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` instead.  Better fit and much less overhead, and

Comment: @FaurIoan-Aurel `shared_ptr` is part of the standard library, but it's in C++11. You may have to switch your compiler to C++11 mode with `-std=c++0x`

Comment: Ouch!Haven't seen that one!Thank's @bames53

Comment: What does `network->reset();` do?

Comment: @Benj: A better approach for that is to use a std::vector<size_t> that stores indices to the other vector<T>. If you modify the vector<T>, the pointers in the vector<T*> will be invalidated, but indices will not.

Comment: I've merged reset() method but as you can see i don't change any pointer stored inside the vector.I just iterate through them and call a method called random() who just init an array with some random numbers!

Comment: @MooingDuck - How do you actually create a vector of std::unique_ptr in that circumstance?  The unique_ptr has to be unique so can't live in two vectors at once nor on the stack unless it's temporary at the point you add it to the vector.  Also shared_ptr has far less of an impact if you use make_shared since then the meta data is stored in one allocation with the data it's self limiting the performance impact.

Comment: @Idelic - That rather depends on how you modify the original vector doesn't it?  If you insert to the front of the original vector<T> you'll screw every index position in your second vector using your approach.  It seems to me that either approach could work and would depend on what you had planned with the original vector.

Comment: @Benj: `vector::emplace_back` is the solution to that.  `std::unique_ptr` has less impact even than `make_shared` since it only takes one allocation _and_ does no reference counting whatsoever.

Comment: @Benj: Of course it depends, I didn't think it was necessary to state the obvious :-) But pointers to elements are much more fragile than indices (e.g. pointers are invalidated by push_back(), indices are not, etc), so I do think a vector<size_t> is a better approach than a vector<T*>.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why you need a `dynamic_cast` inside of `ForwardNetwork::getLayers` unless you are doing some type of polymorphic casting and want to certify that the pointer type that is being cast from can be converted to a `ForwardLayer*` type.  The cast simply shouldn't fail if you are assigning from one `ForwardLayer` pointer to another.  The fact that you're getting `NULL` pointers means that the cast is failing, and I suspect the issue is coming from the difference between a `FeedforwardLayer` and a `ForwardLayer`, but there is not enough code presented here to decipher how your inheritance hierarchy is constructed.

That being said, your `NULL` pointers are not a result of incorrectly adding pointers to your linked list, but instead are resulting from a failed `dynamic_cast`.